# Assign a task to the person chosen in the people picker field

Tags: sharepoint-designer, workflow, people-picker, tasks

I'm fairly new to SharePoint and am just starting out with workflows. At the moment I am trying to create a simple Purchase Order Approval workflow, which should just have these stages:

1. User clicks on +new item in the list and is presented with the form
2. User fills out all required details (description, supplier, currency, amount etc.) including the person that the PO should go to for approval through a people picker field
3. On creation of the new item, the workflow begins by creating a task that is assigned to the person chosen in the people picker field when the new item was created
4. Further workflow steps are as would be expected - Approve / Reject, confirmation email to the person who created the item etc.

Overall I am happy with this process, but the one stumbling block I have is that I can't seem to find a way to assign the task to the person chosen in the form. I'm sure this must be possible and I'm just missing something - any advice would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up rebuilding the list, at which point I had the option to look up the field using the 'Workflow Lookup for a User' and 'Current List' option. I'd made some changes to the original list, such as allowing management of content types (and some other changes I don't remember) which seem to have limited my options. Since falaskaman's above comment is correct, I'd like to mark it as the answer but can't as it is just a comment. If it's reposted as an answer then of course I will.

Edit: Just came back to this question to mark this as an answer, in lieu of being able to mark falaskaman's comment as the answer.

Answer (score 2):

When creating a workflow choose the "Assign a To-Do Item", then when choosing users, select "Workflow Look up for a user" and select "Current List", and the "Assigned to" or whatever the field name you want to draw the users from.

I tried to reword my previous comment in to a more general answer.

EDIT: changed my reply form the unhelpful one, to the comment that was deemed helpful

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, however I run into the same problem. When I go to Select Users, I can't find a way to select the person chosen in the people picker field from the form that kicks off the workflow. I've tried looking through the options from 'Workflow Lookup for a User...' (which is where I would expect to find it), but haven't had any success so far.

Comment: I figured as much, but dont have enough reputation to just comment on your original question :/

The 'Workflow Lookup for a User' doesnt have the 'Current List' option? for me I can choose a column in the list for that category, which would be your 'Assigned to' field or whatever its called

Comment: Solved - I ended up rebuilding the list, at which point I had the option to look up the field using the 'Workflow Lookup for a User' and 'Current List' option. I'd made some changes to the original list, such as allowing management of content types (and some other changes I don't remember) which seem to have limited my options. Since falaskaman's above comment is correct, I'd like to mark it as the answer but can't as it is just a comment. If it's reposted as an answer then of course I will.